# Calling Service Functions

Tags: angularjs

I have following service with 2 functions. I want to call this from my controller so i did but gives me error :-

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('Practices', function ($resource) {

      return {
          UpdatePractice: function () {
              return $resource('/api/practicesUpdate/:practiceId', {
                  practiceId: '@_id'
              }, { //parameters default
                  update: {
                      method: 'PUT'
                  }
              });
          },
          UpdateCreditCard: function () {
              return $resource('/api/practicesCreditCardUpdate/:practiceId', {
                  practiceId: '@_id'
              }, { //parameters default
                  updateCredit: {
                      method: 'PUT'
                  }
              });
          }

      }
  });
```

Calling from controller :-

```
Practices.UpdatePractice.update($scope.practice);
```

[image]

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: ...<omitted>... } has no method 'update'

Comment: use `Practices.UpdatePractice().update($scope.practice);` UpdatePractice is a function not a property

Comment: Good...it works.....pls help me in this too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090297/2-services-merge-in-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Practices.UpdatePractice.update($scope.practice);
```

`UpdatePractice` is a function and needs to be executed first...

```
Practices.UpdatePractice().update($scope.practice);
```