# 2 Services merge in 1

Tags: angularjs

I have following in my `.js` file. I am new to angular. Now instead of writing this separately, I want it to be in one service say `Practices`.

How to do this?

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Practices', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/practices/:statusController/:statusId/:searchController/:searchId/:practiceId/:pageController/:pagenum', {
        practiceId: '@practiceId',
        statusId: '@statusId',
        statusController: '@statusController',
        searchId: '@searchId',
        searchController: '@searchController',
        pagenum: '@pagenum',
        pageController: '@pageController'
    });
}]);

angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('PracticesEdit', function ($resource) {

      return {
          UpdatePractice: function () {
              return $resource('/api/practicesUpdate/:practiceId', {
                  practiceId: '@_id'
              }, { //parameters default
                  update: {
                      method: 'PUT'
                  }
              });
          },
          UpdateCreditCard: function () {
              return $resource('/api/practicesCreditCardUpdate/:practiceId', {
                  practiceId: '@_id'
              }, { //parameters default
                  updateCredit: {
                      method: 'PUT'
                  }
              });
          }

      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('PracticesService', function ($resource) {
    var practices = $resource(...);

    return {
          updatePractice: function () {
             // the same
          },
          updateCreditCard: function () {
             // the same
          },
          practices: practices
      }
  });
```

and then you can use it in controller as

```
PracticesService.practices;
PracticesService.updateCreditCard();
PracticesService.updatePractice();
```

Comment: thankx...but when i call `updatePractice` it gives me error `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'UpdatePractice'`

Comment: I changed the method names to start with lowercase letter, have you copied the code or wrote it correctly?